# Отличие синтаксиса в объявлении массива в качестве поля класса

Tags: c++

Решал задачу и мельком обнаружил вот такой занятый синтаксис, обозначающий массив:

```
template<class T>
class vec
{
    T el[];
    //...
};
```

При чем такой синтаксис прокатывает лишь в структурах и классах, если попробовать объявить массив таким способом вне их(без задания статического размера в квадратных скобках), то компилятор благополучно пошлет далеко и надолго.
Так вот вопрос: чем подобный синтаксис отличается от привычного `T* el`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), и работает только в С, не в С++, и только если это последнее и не единственное поле в структуре.

Если ваш компилятор это принимает, стоит подкрутить настройки.

Это не указатель, а как бы массив нулевого размера (в лоб `T el[0];` - не компилируется). Идея в том, чтобы выделить под структуру память с запасом, а потом размещать в этом запасе элементы массива (произвольное количество), и обращаться к ним через этот псевдо-массив.

По сути, эта фича сама по себе ничего не делает, только упрощает обращение к элементам. Можно было бы с тем же успехом вычислять указатели на них самому.

Comment: А как понять выделена ли память под n-ый элемент этого псевдомассива? Ну то есть, что обращение к ```el[10000]``` приведет меня туда, куда надо.

Comment: Ааа, это определяется количеством памяти, которое я в ручную выделил под структуру, верно?

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов *"определяется количеством памяти, которое я в ручную выделил под структуру"* Да.